# Visual-Studio-Code: How to maximise width of code area?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Red area] When I toggle panels I get an empty space in my workarea.
Pic is the example. Red area is not used.

Already tried:
Use mouse to move borders.
Togle view/apparance

Solution: F1 > toggle centered layout Found it in github issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/53778

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go view->apperance->toggle centered layout.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Just found it at the same time. Thanks anyway. I was making me crazy!